# Only my http://localhost:8080/ mapping works, but the rest of my Mappings in my Controller class do not

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, h2

I am creating a project that functions like an ecommerce website, and my base page `http://localhost:8080` opens up, but if I try adding `"/admin"` or any of the other mappings in the controller class, I get the `404` Whitelabel page.

How can I make any of the other mappings appear properly?

I tried changing the `@ComponentScan` in the main class to

```
"@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.ecommerce.website.service.*", "com.ecommerce.website.controller.*", "com.ecommerce.website.repository.*" })"
```

but that did not solve the issue.

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.ecommerce.website.repository.*")
@ComponentScan("com.ecommerce.website.service.*")
@EntityScan("com.ecommerce.website.model.*")
public class EcommerceWebsiteApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EcommerceWebsiteApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Controller class

```
package com.ecommerce.website.controller;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import com.ecommerce.website.model.Category;
import com.ecommerce.website.service.CategoryService;

//Category ID still having issues
//Need to add methods for Category delete and update methods 
@Controller
public class AdminController {
    
    //Injecting dependency
    @Autowired
    CategoryService categoryService;
    
    //This method maps for /admin endpoint. It shows the adminHome.html page. The method is @GetMapping because you are getting information 
    //@return the adminHome page
    @GetMapping("/admin")
    public String adminHome() {
        
        //Display html page
        return "adminHome";
    }
    
    //This method maps for /admin/categories endpoint. It shows the categories.html page. The method is @GetMapping because you are getting information
    //@return the categories page 
    @GetMapping("/admin/categories")
    public String getCat(Model model) {
        
        model.addAttribute("categories", categoryService.getAllCategories());
        
        //Display html page
        return "categories";
    }
    
    //This method maps for /admin/categories endpoint. It shows the categoriesAdd.html page, but before that, it creates
    //a model that is sent to the html file via Thymeleaf. The categoriesAdd.html page is a form for adding a category
    //The method is @GetMapping because you are getting information
    //@param model will hold the category object so that the form can add information to it 
    //@return the categoriesAdd page 
    @GetMapping("/admin/categories/add")
    public String getCatAdd(Model model) {
        
        //Adding the model name "category", and creating a new Category object and putting it in the model
        model.addAttribute("category", new Category());
        
        //Display html page
        return "categoriesAdd";
    }
    
    //This method maps for /admin/categories endpoint. It allows the user to add a category to the list of categories
    //The method is @PostMapping because you are sending information
    //@param category gets its value from the ModelAttribute, which gets its value from the form
    //@return the categories page 
    @PostMapping("/admin/categories/add")
    public String postCatAdd(@ModelAttribute("category") Category category) {
        
        //Calling categoryService to add the category
        categoryService.addCategory(category);
        
        //Redirecting to page that shows all categories 
        return "redirect:/admin/categories";
    }
```

Service

```
package com.ecommerce.website.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.ecommerce.website.model.Category;
import com.ecommerce.website.repository.CategoryRepository;

@Service
public class CategoryService {

    //Injecting dependency 
    @Autowired
    CategoryRepository categoryRepository;
    
    //This method calls categoryRepository to add a category to the database  
    //@param category is the category that is being added 
    public void addCategory(Category category) {
        
        //Saving the category to the database 
        categoryRepository.save(category);
    }
    
    //This method calls categoryRepository to retrieve a list of categories 
    //@return the list of categories  
    public List<Category> getAllCategories() {
        return categoryRepository.findAll();
    }
    
}
```

Repository

```
package com.ecommerce.website.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.ecommerce.website.model.Category;

@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Integer> {

    

}
```

POJO

```
package com.ecommerce.website.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Entity
@Table
public class Category {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private int id;
    
    private String name;
    
    
    public Category() {
        
    }
    
    public Category(int id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    } 
    
    
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./db
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

server.port=8080
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ecommerce</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecommerce-website</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ecommerce-website</name>
    <description>Ecommerce website using Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>-->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

EDIT
I removed all annotations from the main class, except for @SpringBootApplication and @ComponentScan, so now it looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.ecommerce.website.service.*", "com.ecommerce.website.controller.*", "com.ecommerce.website.repository.*" })
public class EcommerceWebsiteApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EcommerceWebsiteApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Currently what is being shown in my console

```
2022-12-27T22:43:35.202-06:00  INFO 5656 --- [           main] c.e.website.EcommerceWebsiteApplication  : Starting EcommerceWebsiteApplication using Java 17.0.2 with PID 5656 (C:\Users\sohaib\eclipse-workspace\mongoDB-spring-boot\ecommerce-website-h2\target\classes started by sohaib in C:\Users\sohaib**strong text**\eclipse-workspace\mongoDB-spring-boot\ecommerce-website-h2)
2022-12-27T22:43:35.208-06:00  INFO 5656 --- [           main] c.e.website.EcommerceWebsiteApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-12-27T22:43:36.611-06:00  INFO 5656 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-12-27T22:43:36.709-06:00  INFO 5656 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 87 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-12-27T22:43:37.831-06:00  INFO 5656 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-12-27T22:43:37.844-06:00  INFO 5656 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-12-27T22:43:37.844-06:00  INFO 5656 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.1]
2022-12-27T22:43:37.989-06:00  INFO 5656 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-12-27T22:43:37.992-06:00  INFO 5656 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2658 ms
2022-12-27T22:43:38.033-06:00  INFO 5656 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-12-27T22:43:38.299-06:00  INFO 5656 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:file:./db user=SA
2022-12-27T22:43:38.301-06:00  INFO 5656 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-12-27T22:43:38.314-06:00  INFO 5656 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:file:./db'
2022-12-27T22:43:38.475-06:00  INFO 5656 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-12-27T22:43:38.549-06:00  INFO 5656 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.5.Final
2022-12-27T22:43:38.770-06:00  WARN 5656 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000021: Encountered deprecated setting [javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode], use [jakarta.persistence.sharedCache.mode] instead
2022-12-27T22:43:38.926-06:00  INFO 5656 --- [           main] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2022-12-27T22:43:39.774-06:00  INFO 5656 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-12-27T22:43:39.782-06:00  INFO 5656 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-12-27T22:43:39.847-06:00  WARN 5656 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-12-27T22:43:40.038-06:00  INFO 5656 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page template: index
2022-12-27T22:43:40.576-06:00  INFO 5656 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-12-27T22:43:40.587-06:00  INFO 5656 --- [           main] c.e.website.EcommerceWebsiteApplication  : Started EcommerceWebsiteApplication in 5.879 seconds (process running for 6.41)
2022-12-27T22:47:31.683-06:00  INFO 5656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-12-27T22:47:31.684-06:00  INFO 5656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-12-27T22:47:31.685-06:00  INFO 5656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

Comment: try @RestController instead of @ Controller

Comment: Hi, that did not solve the issue.

Comment: what error do you get after changing to it?

Comment: Add `@RequestMapping` to your admin controller.

Comment: seems like you had more extra  stuff you didnt need just do what the answer told you to do and remove the extra stuff from the main and use the @RestController

Comment: @Anon This time, I tried using RestController and RequestMapping("/api") in my controller class and SpringBootApplication in my main class, but I still get the following errors: "UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adminController'", "UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryService'", "BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryRepository'", and "IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.ecommerce.website.model.Category".

Answer (score 0):

Your controllers are simply not scanned by spring because you explicitly asked it to scan only the com.ecommerce.website.service.* package

However, your controllers are in com.ecommerce.website.controller.*

Why do you want to tell spring which scanner component?
Unless you have a good reason to do so, you should let it scan all the packages in your project.

Just put:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class EcommerceWebsiteApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EcommerceWebsiteApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

More information on @ComponentScan : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning

Comment: If I put only @SpringBootApplication, I get these errors such as "UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adminController'", "UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryService'", "BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryRepository'", and "IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.ecommerce.website.model.Category". This is why I was using the other annotations.

Comment: I understand, but you hid another problem instead of solving it. Did you also remove EnableJpaRepositories and ScanEntity ? Can you edit your post with changes ?

Comment: I see. And yes, I removed those two annotations. And I edited the post with changes. The edited main class and new error messages are at the bottom of the post.

Comment: You are using Spring Boot 3, change all "javax" imports to "jakarta". Should solve your problem.
Keep me informed

Comment: I tried doing that, and the program does not give any errors when I run it, but the pages still give me Whitelabel Error Page 404 errors when I try opening them.

Comment: Can you tell me the URL and the Http method? Consider replacing Controller with RestController

Comment: Currently, I am trying to test the @GetMapping("/admin") mapping, so the URL I am using is http://localhost:8080/admin

Comment: To my main post, I added the text it shows in my console. There are no errors, but I was wondering if you see anything that can be causing the pages to not load up.

Comment: Actually, I think I got it working, thank you for your help! It turns out, I was missing some dependencies that were mentioned in the tutorial I am following. I also made @ComponentScan have 0 arguments